# Can't echo to website as data not inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, curl, sdn

I need to troubleshoot a work done by friend. It seems that there is no error as I can launch the website with no problem. When select a choice from drop-down list and click add, it does not insert data to SQL and does not echo back to the website. What I want to troubleshoot is just inserting data to database and display on website. The database and table have no error as I tried redoing it many times with no luck.

I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form") && ($_POST['InputSwitch'] != "") && ($_POST['InputFromPort'] != "") && ($_POST['InputToPort'] != "")) {

//Start of Add Flow
$flow = '{"flow":{"cookie":"0x2032195","priority": 30000, "idle_timeout": 0, "hard_timeout": 0,"match":[{"in_port":'.$_POST["InputFromPort"].'}],"actions":[{"output":'.$_POST["InputToPort"].'}]}}';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $flow);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://127.0.0.1:8443/sdn/v2.0/of/datapaths/".$_POST['InputSwitch']."/flows");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result3 = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
//End of Add Flow

//Start of Add Flow
$flow2 = '{"flow":{"cookie":"0x2032195","priority": 30000, "idle_timeout": 0, "hard_timeout": 0,"match":[{"in_port":'.$_POST["InputToPort"].'}],"actions":[{"output":'.$_POST["InputFromPort"].'}]}}';

$curl2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $flow2);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_URL,"https://127.0.0.1:8443/sdn/v2.0/of/datapaths/".$_POST['InputSwitch']."/flows");
curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result4 = curl_exec ($curl2);
curl_close ($curl2);
//End of Add Flow

$query = "SELECT * FROM port_switching";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $table[$i]=$row['switching_id'];
    $table[$i+1]=$row['switch'];
    $table[$i+2]=$row['port_in'];
    $table[$i+3]=$row['port_out'];
    $i+=4;
}
if((array_search($_POST['InputFromPort'], $table)) != false)
{
    $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE port_switching SET port_in=%s WHERE port_in=%s",
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputFromPort'], "text"),
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputFromPort'], "text"));
      mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
}


$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO port_switching (switch, port_in, port_out) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputSwitch'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputFromPort'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputToPort'], "text"));

  $insertSQL2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO port_switching (switch, port_in, port_out) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputSwitch'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputToPort'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['InputFromPort'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
 $Result2 = mysql_query($insertSQL2, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
```

Tried putting echo/print here after $Result2 and it give back parse error (unexpected t_echo/print). He said not to add anymore code from here because its done.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

quote: mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )

is $localhost the link_identifier? I would guess it's not..

If not, simply remove that arg and use the mysql_query() that only takes 1 arg (the query). Same with the select_db() function. Assuming you only have 1 mysql connection (link_identifier), it'll be used by default.

Comment: This is my $localhost (from other php script)

$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost)

Comment: @IntelX7 `mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost) or die('Unable to select db, error: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die('Unable to INSERT, error: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<br />Can you see this?';` If you don't see any message, try to "view page source", maybe it's not being displayed.

Comment: When I "view page source", it only shows the html code

Comment: @IntelX7 The errors you mentioned to CodeCanyon: Sounds like the table is empty so the "SELECT *..." is returning an empty set..which means the while() body never executes, and leaves $table uninitialized..which causes that error. You should add debugging messages to verify. Easiest fix (without checking for empty set returned) might be to change the following line (added the i>0 check)
`if(($i > 0) && (array_search(... `  ..Since you don't see the error messages, that means the insert is working, or that code isn't being run. Add debugging echos() to verify the script is running to end.

Comment: As your code currently is, once there is data in the table, and you go to UPDATE a row, you will also INSERT a new row with the same data ..you need to add an else{} clause to `if(($i > 0) && (array_search($_POST['InputFromPort'], $table) != false)) `  , or some other way to control program flow/logic. (?) Just for debugging, use the $i > 0 check and see what happens, but eventually you should properly check for empty set returned and change flow control accordingly.

Comment: Tried adding $i > 0, echo $Result1, still the same. The page still load but nothing comes out. I'm not sure if the code that makes it not to work is under if/else or the insert into.

Comment: After adding the $i>0, did the 2 errors go away?? Help me, help you..add echos throughout the code and figure out where it's quitting; if nothing is being echoed out, I'm assuming there is some error that is causing php to stop interpreting the rest of the code..."add debugging echos() to verify the script is running to end." My last guess is that sprintf() is failing because 1) it doesn't like the value returned from GetSqlValueString() having single-quotes around it, or 2) it expects a named $variable (?). Echo out the query and verify sprintf() is working as expected.

Comment: The 2 errors did go away... I add echos to check the script but nothing came out

Comment: Do I really need the if isset?

Comment: I am unable to help, sorry. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use single isset() for the submit button instead of multiple isset() with post values.Once you add the data, did you check the database to verify whether values have added.Because sometimes although script doesn't show any errors, inserting values can be avoided.And try to enable showing errors by adding this to script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I did check the database. There are no values

Comment: OK.That means your data insertion to the database is also not working.Did you enable the php error reporting and check?

Comment: there are 2 errors. PHP notice:Undefined variable: table in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AddRemove.php on line 134 and PHP warning:array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/AddRemove.php on line 134. It's after the while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))